# How to read and use serialized binary data without deserialize in c#

Tags: c#

How to read and mapping the serialized binary file in c#?

I use BinaryFormatter to serialize my DataTree class.
And here is my target class which want to be serialized.

```
[Serializable()]
public class AppData
{
     public string name = "";
     public int value = 0;
     public AppData() {}
     public AppData(string _name, int _value)
     {
         name = _name;
         value = _value;
     }
}


public enum TreeType
{
    Type1,
    Type2,
    Type3
}
[Serializable()]
public class DataTree
{
    public TreeType Type { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<AppData> AppDataInfos { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, AppDataTree> ChildTrees { get; set; }

    public AppDataTree(TreeType type, string categoryName)
    {
        Type = type;
        CategoryName = categoryName;
        AppDataInfos = new List<AppData>();
        ChildTrees = new Dictionary<string, DataTree>();
    }
    public DataTree FindChildTree(string categoryName)
    {
        if (ChildTrees.ContainsKey(categoryName) == false)
            return null;
        return ChildTrees[categoryName];
    }


}
```

It has dictionary and list member.
I serialized DataTree instance and saved to binary file for cache.

And then i want to read this binary serialized data file and just mapping to memory without deserialize. because deserialize is too slow.(Sadly it is very very slow. It is slower than no caching)
(I serialize and save this to binary file because of cache)

Maybe if i capture the DataTree instance and save to binary file and read it for mapping to memory, how should i gonna do? or does anyone has idea? Like fast serialize/deserialize solutions....and so on.

Comment: What your describing *is* deserialization.  How big is the file when you save it?

Comment: If you say that deserialization is slow, then prove that the deserialization is bottleneck and not the file reading.

Comment: @Reniuz I used StopWatch and check it for twice.  First i check the elapsed time of file reading and it is under 0.1sec. And next i check the elapsed time of deserialize the byte data which is from the file and it is between 10sec ~ 16sec.

Comment: @Archer The file size is about 2000KB ~ 4000KB, and deserialization means BinaryFormatter's Deserailize() method that deserialize the serialized binary data Well.. in originally i already used json to save or load file. json is a little fast , but i want more faster than it. So i thought i must save the data by binary. If i save it json string (text) then, i will need json tree making time and json parse time. If i save the Data instance's data, then i must serialize it. Deserialize may need when read this. Sadly, deserialize is much slower then json text parse time.

Comment: I suspect the nesting could be responsible for a large chunk of the deserialization time.  Just to test, could you take a real set of data and flatten it, so you're not using the ChildTrees property at all, and see if that serializes/deserializes any quicker.  I'm not suggesting this as a fix, but it will help indicate if the nesting *is* an issue.  If not then ignore the suggestion, but if it does help then at least you'll be rethinking in the right direction.  I also think this may be a total clutch at straws, but it's worth ruling out.